# The number of combinations $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $a \cdot b = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, ring-theory, prime-numbers

This question is about a ring for some chosen $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I wanted to find the number $M_n$ of combinations $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ can be found such that $a \cdot b = 0$ and $a\neq 0 \neq b$. I hoped that I could find one formula that works for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, in a manner that we can maximize the quotient $\frac{M_n}{n}$

---

**What I did**

First of all, we can find a bound in a very rough way, namely.
$$
(n - \phi(n))^2 \quad = \quad n^2 \left(1 - \prod_{p |n}(1-\frac 1p) \right)
$$
Another thing I thought about is that if $(a,b)$ is such a combination, then we also have:
$$
(a,-b) \ , \ (-a,b) \ , \ (-a,-b) \ , \ 
(b,a) \ , \ (b,-a) \ , \ (-b,a) \ , \ (-b,-a)
$$
So each pair we would find would give a set of at most seven other pairs.

If we want to count in the most straight-forward way, I believe that a zero-divisor $a$, and look for a value $b$ such that $a\cdot b = 0$. But if we want to find those values $b$, we have to make use of factorisation in prime numbers of $n$.

---

I could use your help here. (If you want me to try to make I big formula of what could be the number of combination I seek, please tell me. I thought it would be useless here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $a \in \mathbb Z_n$, $a \cdot b = 0 \iff ab \equiv 0 \pmod n$. This will occur exactly when $$\frac n {(a,n)} \big\vert\ b$$which can happen exactly $\big((a,n)-1\big)$ times: since we must have $0< b<n$, possible values for $b$ are $$\frac{n}{(a,n)},\frac{2n}{(a,n)},\frac{3n}{(a,n)},\ldots,\frac{\big((a,n)-1\big)n}{(a,n)}$$

Hence, you are looking to calculate $$\sum_{a=1}^{n-1}\big((a,n)-1\big)=\operatorname P(n)-(2n-1)$$
where $\operatorname P(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^n\operatorname{gcd}(a,n)$ is [Pillai's arithmetical function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai's_arithmetical_function).

Comment: If n is prime, this always gives 0

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin: Which is expected, if $n$ is prime then $ab \equiv 0 \pmod{n} \implies a \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ or $b \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

Comment: And for $n=4,6$ i get $1,4$

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin yes that's correct. However, I don't think there's a nice form for this function (I've edited the answer since last time)

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote $-(2n-1)$. Shouldn't you erase the $2$

Comment: The $2n-1$ comes from the fact that $P(n)$ is the sum from $1$ to $n$, but your function needs $1$ to $n-1$

Comment: I don't understand why this works. Do you think that the link you gave me shows me why?

Comment: Which part don't you understand? I can try and add some detail to that bit? The link is just a definition of the Pillai function from wikipedia and isn't very enlightening I'm afraid

Comment: @Mathmo123, I lose you when you say: "This happens exactly $ggd(a,n)-1$ times." How do you know that? That is the only thing that bothers me right now. If you tell me how you found this equality, we can end this.

Comment: Added more detail - is that clearer now?

Comment: I got it now. Thank you